# Javascript Plugin Development , Extending Libraries

Tags: plugins, javascript

i got two javascript objects `api` and `myApi` :

```
var api = {};
api.foo = function(){ ... };
api.foo2 = function(){ ... };

var myApi = {};
myApi.foo = function(){ ...};
myApi.myFoo = function(){ ...};
myApi.myFoo2 = function(){ ...};
```

i want to add all `myApi.*` functions to `api` object without overriding `api.foo`.

Indeed, i want learn how to extend APIs to each other and developing plugins with javascript.

What are the best practices in this subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question, you can modify the `merge` method I use in some of my code:

```
if (typeof Object.merge !== 'function') {
    Object.merge = function (o1, o2) { // Function to merge all of the properties from one object into another
        for(var i in o2) { o1[i] = o2[i]; }
        return o1;
    };
}
```

To not overwrite preexisting objects, you would have to add a check:

```
if (typeof Object.merge !== 'function') {
    Object.merge = function (o1, o2) { // Function to merge all of the properties from one object into another
        for(var i in o2) { if(!(i in o1)) o1[i] = o2[i]; }
        return o1;
    };
}
```